# Problema con Count laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo lo siguiente lo cual funciona perfecto pero si quiero ademas traer otro dato como el user_id que se encuentra dentro de la misma tabla donde hago el conteo me da un error. alquilen sabe cual podría ser la solución?

```
public function scopeCantidadclientes($arvg){
    return $arvg->select(DB::raw('count(credito_id) as cantidad'),'credito_id')
                ->groupBy('credito_id')
                ->get(); }
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. ¿Dónde estás poniendo el nombre de la tabla? Prueba así (donde dice `tutabla` pon el nombre de la tabla): **`return $arvg = DB::table('tutabla')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(credito_id) as cantidad, credito_id, user_id'))
                     ->groupBy('credito_id')
                     ->get();`** En la documentación además no se separa cada columna por comillas simples, sino que se pone la lista completa de columnas entre comillas simples. No sé si esto también influya.

Comment: También se puede separar cada columna y ponerla entre comillas y es válido @A.Cedano

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración @shadow, no tengo Laravel para probarlo. Entonces el error sería que falta la tabla simplemente.

Comment: La tabla con el método table o el llamado al modelo que tenga asociado con dicha tabla